# Subsets of divisors

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many subsets of the set of divisors of $72$ (including the empty set) contain only composite numbers? For example, $\{8,9\}$ and $\{4,8,12\}$ are two such sets.

I know $72$ is $2^3\cdot 3^2$, so there are $12$ divisors.  Besides $2$ and $3$, there are $10$ composite divisors.  Would this mean $\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+...+\binom{10}{10}$?  If so, how would you calculate this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 10 composite divisors. ($4,8,6,12,24,9,18,36,72$).  Any set of divisors that contains only composite numbers must be a subset of this set of 10.  Conversely, any subset of this set of 10 is a subset that contains only composite numbers.

So your problem is how to count how many subsets there are of this set of 10. Do you know a formula or a way of counting the numbers of subsets of a set?

Comment: I don't know one.

Comment: @BobJoe Here are three things you might consider:  1. Suppose $S$ is a set with $n$ elements, and $T$ is a subset of $S$.  Then each of the $n$ elements of $S$ might, or might not be in $T$.  2. Try working out some small examples, say count the number of subsets of a set with 1 element, then the number of subsets of a set with 2 elements, and so on, and see if you notice a pattern.  3. Look in the index of your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Since $72=2^3 3^2$ as you say, it has 12 positive divisors and therefore (eliminating 1, 2, and 3) has 9 composite positive divisors.

Since the number of subsets of a set with 9 elements is $2^9=512$ (including the empty set), there should be 512 such subsets.

(Notice that this is the same as $\binom{9}{0}+\binom{9}{1}+\binom{9}{2}+\cdots+\binom{9}{9}$.)

Answer (score 0):

The $10$ element set has $2^{10}$ subsets.

Comment: Is this including the empty set?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the set of composite divisors, $S$, then $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the set of subsets of $S$. This is calles "parts of $S$". And $|\mathcal{P}(S)| = 2^{|S|}$. So in your case, there are $2^{10} = 1024$ subsets of the set of divisors of $72$ that only contain composite numbers.

Comment: Including the empty set?

Comment: @BobJoe Yes. Look at it this way:
For evey element, you can add it to a set or not, so for every element you have two choices. You have $10$ elements, therefore, there are $2^{10}$ ways to do those choices. The one where you choose not to include any element, is the empty set.

Comment: Also:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$
So your original idea still works (but you didn't include the empty set: $\binom{10}{0}$)